# Wanting to hash passwords using password_hash but still want to be able to display them with an eye like lastpass php

Tags: php, encryption, hash

As the title says I'm trying to use PHP's password_hash function but I know that it is one way hashing so if I use it the password will be unable to be unhashed.

That being said, I want to be able to have an eye next to a password box (like LastPass) within the system that I'm working with that can display the password for admin users of the site but I'm not sure how to do this. Is there a function within PHP or some library that will allow for secure hashing or encryption so that this is possible? Is there another way to do this securely?

I've been looking around stack overflow for a while now just trying to find an answer to this but have to find anything that is close to what I'm wanting to do.

For a quick frame of reference for this. The users of the site can allow for 3rd party companies to login to retrieve files that are being shared with them. The users create the password and share it with the 3rd party. I want to make sure that when the passwords are secured but still allow the users of the site to go back and lookup the password for the 3rd party companies should they forget their password.

Comment: While i think its a bad idea, store the hashed and unhashed version. use the hashed version for checking the login, but show the unhashed version when required. you could store the unhashed passwords encrypted in the db, but that adds little real security

Comment: If you really want to do this .. (and really you don't). You don't want to hash the password, rather encrypt it using gpg or something similar. At least that way someone would have to get your secret key in the event of a breach. Still, don't do this. Too much can go wrong.

Comment: @rtfm I agree that it is a bad idea and it's not something I want to do. Thanks for the help though. :-)

Comment: @Cfreak you are right and I really don't want to do that either. Thanks for the help though. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... that will allow for ***secure*** hashing or encryption so that *[displaying the password for admin users]* is possible?

You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means. :-)

Password hashing can either be secure *or* it can be reversible.

The whole point of password hashing is to be *non-reversible.* If you want the original password, you're going to have to store it (keeping in mind how insecure this actually is).

At a bare minimum, you'd want the plaintext password somewhere totally separate from, and inaccessible to, the outside world. But the ground is littered from the corpses of password files that companies thought were secure from the general public, so my advice is to steer well clear of this.

Comment: I will try my best to avoid doing this. It's not something I want to do in the first place though it was the first thought that came to mind. Thanks for the help and confirming what I already thought. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot get the original plaintext password from a hash. That's the entire point. The plaintext password is a *secret* that only the user is supposed to know. The secrecy of their password is the only security measure they have. If the password is "publicly" known then the security is out of their hands. And if *anyone* besides them knows the password, even if it's just your server, it becomes harder and harder to control *who* knows the password and it's only a matter of time until it leaks entirely.

That is why you don't want even your server to know the actual password, and to only store an irreversible hash of it.

If you want to store the password in a way that is reversible, at the very least you should store it such that even the server itself could not see the plaintext. Meaning, even if you encrypt it, encrypt it in a way that the server itself cannot decrypt it. Because if your server can decrypt it, so can anyone with access to that server. For instance, use entirely client-side encryption within the browser and require the user to enter their password in some way which will decrypt the stored password. Of course, this limits *who* will be able to see the password, **which is the entire point.**

If you need concrete encryption schemes to design this, it's best to ask at http://security.stackexchange.com or perhaps https://crypto.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I will defiantly take the time to look into those options. I like the sound of them but I think I might just have to avoid dealing with this for now and only do hashing. I'll probably make this a project to try to implement down the road. Thanks for the help. :-)